# How to login to a session in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, window-manager, session, lxsession

I am trying to install `bspwm` by following [this](https://dev.to/l04db4l4nc3r/bspwm-a-bare-bones-window-manager-44di) . Now after installing `bspwm` , I have to put `exec bspwm` in my `.xsessions` file. But I have only `bspwm.desktop` and `ubuntu.desktop` under `~/usr/share/xsessions`. Secondly, I dont get a `settings` button on my login screen like this one which enables me to set the session manually.

[image: pic]

---

So , how to get that button ?